# How to tell which side of a Meanwell Encapsulated is AC and which is DC?

Tags: power-supply, ac, 5v

I received an AC/DC Encapsulated PSU from Meanwell.
The datasheet [Meanwell IRM 60 5ST](https://www.meanwellusa.com/productPdf.aspx?i=687) seems to suggest that the the terminal block with two screws is for the AC while the terminal blocks with 4 screws are the 5v outputs.
However it looks to me as if the plastic chassis has been swapped, perhaps when they fitted they made a mistake? I have used the same model in the past, but this is the first time I see this.
Can anybody help me figure out which one is which? (AC or 5v)
Thanks!
[image: PSU AC to 5V]

Comment: Remove the plastic cover, it's easy. Then you'll know.

Comment: Ask Meanwell or seller what to do when you have a faulty product.

Comment: It certainly looks like the cover was put on backwards, but it might be worth an email to the manufacturer to confirm.  If you don't mind taking the slight risk, you could just apply AC to the 2 terminal block and see if you get the right DC voltages on the other side.

Comment: The top cover has one corner keyed to provide a guide for label application. It's been laser marked instead. It looks like it was sent through the laser marking machine in the wrong orientation.

Comment: +1 for "email the manufacturer", -1 for "just apply AC and see if it blows up"

Comment: @user253751 LOL, looking at the markings I think the risk to applying AC to the 2 terminal block is pretty small.  They almost certainly put it through the laser marking machine in the wrong orientation.  There's little chance that the design changed to have the AC side be the 4 terminal block but they left the marking showing 4 terminals for DC and 2 for AC.

Comment: I would pry off the cover to ensure your assumption which seems correct.

Comment: overwhelming evidence that the label is backward ...https://duckduckgo.com/?q=irm-60-5st&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the last page of the [DATASHEET](https://www.meanwellusa.com/productPdf.aspx?i=687) tells us that the label is printed upside down.

Refer to the pinouts in the datasheet and ignore the label.

[image]

Note the location of the cut corner on the label area.

Comment: Nice!!!! Thank you!

Comment: You might be wise to be cautious in using this power supply in anything important. It is not unknown for a whole bunch of assembly line rejects to find their way on to the grey market and be sold. Usually the laser marking is not done until after the final test is passed, so it's possible this part was a failed part that was laser marked later. Not saying it's not a genuine Meanwell with just a badly marked cover, but just consider the other possibilities before you use it in a critical application.

Comment: I would ask Meanwell if the power supply is counterfeit.  If it isn't, ask for a replacement.

Comment: Thank you, that is a very good point! I bought it from RS online, their customer care had just closed when I realised the part had the issue. I am calling them first thing tomorrow morning!